# nonlinear frequency response

Tags: matlab, filter

I have a (very) long signal in the form of vector, and I would like to apply a non-linear frequency response on that vector. For example:

```
v=rand(1000000,1);
nonlinFreqResponse = @(f,v) sqrt(v).*1/f;
V=wfft(v); %windowed FFt, cant do FFT on the entire signal
....?
```

Note that since the signal is long, running FFT on the entire signal is computationally complex and not feasible.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for help with here.  Matlab has several built-in window functions.  Or you could do your own filter and use any of Matlab's various filter functions.

Comment: My problem that I would like a window function that is both frequency AND gain dependant

Comment: Sounds like you need to build your window in the frequency domain, fft it to the time domain, then do a convolution of it with your signal.

Comment: fft is in frequency only. I need mixed. i.e. different frequency response for different gain

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best solution is to apply the FFT as usual.  Then apply a correction factor, or a transfer function, to your vector that is gain dependent.  I'm not sure what's going on with your code, so can't help you there. Good luck!